# Hbase and GAE DataStore compatibility

Tags: google-app-engine, nosql, google-cloud-datastore, hbase

How compatible are Hbase and DataSore in terms of design and API. That is, if I convert my GAE app to run completely in a local (non GAE) setup, how much effort it takes to migrate the data into Hbase? Are there lot of misfits (example, the way index created etc). Can one write a small layer to abstract away the difference.

Comment: can you further explain your use case. What do you mean by offline? when you run the GAE development server there is already a local abstraction of the datastore.

Comment: Sorry for not being explicit. Say my application target online users, and some offline usage (corporate). So it is not the development env. Mainly, can I migrate (switch between) the data to an established non-sql system.

Comment: I still don't understand what do you mean by 'offline usage (corporate)'. Are you planing to run some analysis tasks on the data. If so you can use cron jobs or taks queues on GAE. You can downlaod all the data if you need to migrate. See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata#Downloading_and_Uploading_All_Data for details.

Comment: say the program need to work without internet access (as an intranet app). If the code can take care of 'other differences', can hbase or something similar can take care of switching between storage. I am reading about http://appscale.cs.ucsb.edu/.

Comment: I would have a look at html5 web storage http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html and see if it meets your offline requirements.  At the moment I believe you have not provided sufficient information for any sort of detailed response.

Comment: I edited my qn to the crux of the problem. thanks for the help